# How do I add a new page to the customer account dashboard?

Tags: magento

I have edited the customer.xml file to add a new link to the dashboard page. I added the following line

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>newpage</name><path>customer/newpage/</path><label>My New Page</label></action>
```

I've also added the following block to customer.xml

```
<customer_newpage_index translate="label">
    <label>Customer My newpage</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <update handle="newpage"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/newpage" name="newpage" before="-" template="customer/newpage.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_newpage_index>
```

And added a template file at template/customer/newpage.phtml

The link displays, but I get a 404 page when I view /customer/newpage/

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: — Too long for a single StackOverflow answer, but I've **just** covered exactly this in a new Magento tutorial: http://alanstorm.com/magento_create_customer_page  May be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a controller called `NewpageController.php` and in it have an action called `indexAction`. It is probably not a good idea to add this controller inside of the Customer module, because that is in `core`, and we *never* touch `core`. Instead, what you probably want to do is create your own module and put the controller inside of that. It can still be added as one of the links to the sidebar like you have done, but from the outside so that when you upgrade Magento you won't lose your controller.

Comment: Thanks, this kinda got me going in the correct direction. I had to leave the link in my customer.xml file as when I tried to addlink in my new module I got a missing helper error. Unsure as to why I would need the helper class?

Alternatively, could I have just built a CMS page and included the customer account navigation block?

Comment: Perhaps - I've never tried it. If you edit the layout xml for the CMS page you might be able to achieve this.